# How to increase data size of a field in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, column

I have a requirement where I need to increase data size of a field in SharePoint.

This field currently can hold 12 characters and I want to increase it to 15 characters.

Pls, share your suggestion.

Comment: What's the datatype of your field?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a `single line of Text` with a limited number of characters

**To set the number of characters for `single line of Text`, do the following:**

- Go to List Settings
- Below Columns > Click on your column Name to open the `Column Settings`.
- Set the `Max number of characters` to 15 or as you prefer as shown below:

[image]

Check also, [SharePoint Column limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits#column-limits).